# Deployable services on Azure Stacks HCI

Tags: azure, cloud, architecture

What is the **list** of the resources/services that can be deployed to a hybrid Azure Stacks HCI appliance?

**Context**

I am doing an assessment about whether existing on-public-cloud applications can be deployed to on-prem environments. The ultimate goal is a list of required software changes/reenginering.

Since our apps are currently bound very tight to Azure and its services, I expect the short answer is that they can't be deployed right away. But I need to understand, in particular, what services, especially in PaaS, that Azure currently provides on the cloud can be provided on-prem by adopting Azure private & hybrid solutions.

`Azure Stacks Hub` is the private cloud solution by MS Azure to deploy Azure apps on premise. `Azure Stacks HCI` is a hybrid cloud that allows to perform some workload (e.g. sensitive workloads, PII processing) on premise. Running on prem is often a cultural requirement more than regulatory in my experience. I wouldn't like to expand because it will be a long dissertation.

I have found a [Marketplace list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-marketplace-azure-items?view=azs-2008) of services available for Stacks Hub private cloud. I assume they run air-gapped, but it's not the scope of this question.

By narrowing the scope to the PaaS services we require, I will make a list and share my current findings. Today, this is a very high-level analysis.

- Angular FE via static web app: possible. VMs and containers supported
- .NET Core BE: possible as above
- SQL Server: possible, because it is cited everywhere
- Blob storage: Stacks is full about storage. Not sure, however, that the Stacks storage is compatible with existing applications using Blob Storage APIs
- Azure Key Vault: is it possible to deploy an instance of AKV to a private server or is it available only on public? For example, I haven't found it in Hub Marketplace
- Azure Data Factory: probably not available, but I can't find information whether I can deploy ADF privately
- Azure App Insights: can we collect stats on private instances? Probably not, only on the hybrid (and deployed to the public part of the cloud)